# No change when I deploy the site with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm trying for several days to deploy my site with Firebase. I'm using Ubuntu 16.10, but still no change. Everything worked with me fine, deploy completed successfully, but I don't know why I can't see my site on! 
Any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Comment: Without knowing how to reproduce this problem, there is not a lot we can do here. If you'd like help troubleshooting your specific problem, you can also [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that I was deploying to a different alias of the same project. You can have many aliases within a project (i.e. versions of the same project) , but only one alias will be visible to people visiting your site.

Entering `firebase use <alias_or_project_id>` in terminal will let you set the alias name you'd like to use. 
To deploy that specific alias, run `firebase deploy --project <alias_or_project_id>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out my browser (chrome) was just caching the old site. Clearing the cache and hard reloading fixed the problem. Hope this helps someone.